# Drupal 7 SSO via simplesaml_auth module

Tags: drupal-7, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

Currently developing a SSO method for my Drupal website. I've installed simplesamlphp successfully and also configured it. I have also installed the simplesaml_auth module on my website and the SSO procedure works fine. The only problem I am having is when a user logs in via the SSO method I need to redirect them to a certain page when login is successful and I am not sure where to edit the code to be able to do this.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add redirect condition wise in below function of simplesaml auth module

```
simplesamlphp_auth_loginpage() {

change drupal_goto path here to set new redirect.

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've tried setting a goto path in that function on the simplesaml auth module page but was met with an error message saying simplesamlphp_auth_loginpage has already been declared on another page and that page being simplesamlphp_auth.pages.inc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add a destination menu item id query parameter in the SAML login url to which it should b redirected after successful login.

Generally the SAML menu item is **saml_login** which makes the SAML login url like https://[SITE_NAME]/saml_login now just add it a destination query parameter like https://[SITE_NAME]/saml_login/?destination=after_login

Where after_login should be a custom menu_item defined in any of the custom module containing the callback function for redirection.

If needed any existing menu item of core or contributed module can be also used in the destination.